# MomentJS not converting date correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, date, momentjs

I'm getting records from Mongolab with the format: `"2016-02-07T04:11:27.667Z"`

To display the dates, I am converting them to `MM-DD-YYYY` to make them more human readable:

```
obj.converted_date = moment(obj.date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

For some reason, it's converting records on 2/7/2016 to 2/6/2016:

```
converted_date: "02-06-2016"
date: "2016-02-07T04:11:27.667Z"
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Check your timezones.

Comment: "2/6/2016" is ambiguous, better to use something like "6-Feb-2016" or similar that uses the month name, not number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because dates represent in "local time" rather than "utc" that they are stored in unless you ask it to:

```
 moment(obj.date).utc().format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

So the difference is represented by your configured timezone adjusting the date.

See [UTC](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) in the docs.

Comment: So Moment is assuming my time retrieved from Mongo is in Local. So Moment's `utc()` converts `UTC -> local` right?

Comment: @Growler Mongo always stores in UTC. It's a default action of momentjs that "formatted" dates are shown as "local". Also even if you sent Mongo a local time, it would still be stored as UTC.

Comment: Blakes, I push this update to live AWS EC2 server. This code fix is appearing on the server, but the date ranges are once again missing records for the next day. The EC2 instance seems to be configured for `UTC` time. Why is this problem occurring?

Comment: @Growler Sounds like you have another question with a different context. [Ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) showing the full details of your problem. Just in your short description this would appear to be something different, and likely related to your data.

Answer (score 2):

Your time is indicated in UTC because of the `Z` at the end of it.  Instead of using `"2016-02-07T04:11:27.667Z"`, it should be `"2016-02-07T04:11:27.667"` if you want it to be local time.

Or, as Blakes Seven suggests, you can display the time in UTC and it will show you the identical time rather than the time offset for the local timezone of the server.