# AWS EC2 UTC timezone conversion off by a day with moment JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, amazon-ec2, momentjs

Yesterday I posted this question about MongoDB UTC record timestamp issues when using `MomentJS`:

[MomentJS not converting date correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303207/momentjs-not-converting-date-correctly)

Blakes Seven's answer solved the issue locally, but when I deployed to AWS EC2, the problem reoccurred. Here are the steps I took to understand the issue:

- I verified the Elastic Beanstalk instance was using the correct `zip` from S3 bucket. So the code fix is definitely live.
- EC2 location: `US East (N. Virginia)`
- The request location to MongoDB for records is the same for the local and live
- Launch Time: `October 21, 2015 at 4:51:31 PM UTC-4 (2684 hours)`: I can't find the actual time zone config of my EC2, but this tells me it's UTC.

So my questions are:

- How can I verify that my EC2 is set to `UTC` time
- Is the server timezone even the issue? Somehow the dates aren't being read or parsed correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have a simular issue. Everything was going fine with `moment.locale('fr')` but wen wrong on AWS EBS/EC2.
I solved it by using `moment-timezone` and force to 'Europe/Paris':

`moment.tz('Europe/Paris')`